# mysql - Displaying data based on inner join result

Tags: mysql, sql

**Edit: I just realised I'm not using the manager's ID anywhere here so the query can't tell which manager level to look for.**

This is a very simple problem where I am going wrong somewhere. I have a mock help desk ticketing system. Each ticket is assigned a difficulty level from 1-3 and each manager has a support level of 1-3.

I want the manager to search for tickets that are open and have the same difficulty level as his support level.

My SQL code below is displaying every open ticket from levels 1-3. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ticket
                            INNER JOIN manager
                            ON ticket.difficulty = manager.level
                            WHERE ticket.status = 'open'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ticket
                            INNER JOIN manager
                            ON ticket.difficulty = manager.level
                            WHERE ticket.status = 'open' && ticket.difficulty='yourmanagerssupportlevel'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add another where condition to filter by manager.level.

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
                        INNER JOIN manager
                        ON ticket.difficulty = manager.level
                        WHERE ticket.status = 'open' and manager.level=1
```